# Weakly compact cardinals

Tags: set-theory

In Exercises 17.17 and 17.18 of Jech's Set Theory book, he shows that if the language $L_\kappa$ satisfies the Weak Compactness Theorem, then $\kappa$ is a weakly inaccessible cardinal.  Also, in Theorem 17.13 of the same book, it is shown that *if* $\kappa$ is strongly inaccessible, then $L_\kappa$ satisfies the Weak Compactness Theorem if and only if $\kappa$ is weakly compact.

This seems to suggest that it is consistent that there is a cardinal $\kappa$ for which $L_\kappa$ satisfies the Weak Compactness Theorem but such that $\kappa$ is only weakly inaccessible and not strongly inaccessible.

Can anyone provide a reference for such a consistency result?

Comment: Have you checked Kanamori?

Comment: Assuming a measurable it's consistent that there is a weakly inaccessible $\kappa$ not strongly inaccessible satisfying the tree property (since there is a model having a real-valued measurable cardinal below $2^{\aleph_0}$). But $\kappa^{<\kappa}>\kappa$ in this model, and so the tree property alone is not enough to prove that $\mathcal{L}_{\kappa, \kappa}$ has the compactness property.

Comment: @godelian Sorry, but I don’t see how that answers the question.

Comment: due to Solovay and Kunen unpublished (I think in $Add(\omega, \kappa)$ $\kappa$ should have the weak compactness property) but Williams Boos has an article extending their results (my internest sucks now but the title may be something like: weak compactness theorem without strong inaccessibility).

Comment: @Isaac It doesn't, it indicates a model similar to the one you are looking for but replacing the compactness property of $\mathcal{L}_{\kappa, \kappa}$ by the tree  property for $\kappa$. If only we had $\kappa^{<\kappa}=\kappa$, then the tree property would imply it.

Comment: @Jing  Thanks for the reference. It seems very relevant. Unfortunately I still can’t pinpoint a result in there that answers my exact question. It seems to point to the fact that the Weak Compactness Theorem can hold often. But I can’t find an instance where it is guaranteed that the cardinal is not strongly inaccessible.

Comment: Theorem 1.3 of that paper gives it. It says after $Add(\omega, \mu)$ where $\mu$ is a measurable cardinal, in $V[G]$ there exists $\kappa<\mu=2^\omega$ that satisfies the Weak Compactness Theorem. Such cardinal can't be strongly inaccessible obviously.

Comment: @Jing Thanks!  I don’t know how I missed that...